# Need help to display the return of SOAP request from webservice

Tags: java, android, object, soap

I try to make my first android app !
I call a webservice with ksoap2 to get details of my account.
I have a function witch return a Array (resultRequestSOAP).
In the resultRequestSOAP  there is an ARRAY of object.
Below my function :

```
    public Array listall(String session){
    final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://www.nubio.net/soap/vps#listAll";
    final String METHOD_NAME = "listAll";
    final String NAMESPACE = "http://www.nubio.net/soap/vps";
    final String URL = "http://www.nubio.net/soap/vps";
    Array myArray = null;
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    //SoapObject 
    request.addProperty("session",session);
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    try 
        {
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            resultRequestSOAP =  envelope.getResponse();
            //retour = resultRequestSOAP.toString();
            if(resultRequestSOAP != null){
               myArray = (Array)resultRequestSOAP; 
            }
        }
    catch (Exception aE)
        {
    aE.printStackTrace ();;
        }
    return myArray;

}
```

I test the function to return string and it's works fine, but i need to show the array on the screen.
How can i display the array in the resultRequestSOAP; ?
But the original return of the soap in resultRequestSOAP; is :

```
array(
   0 => Object{
     vps_id      : int
     ip          : string
     hostname    : string
     password    : string (optional)
     os          : string
     os_arch     : integer
     os_distri   : string
     expire      : string (DATE TIME)
   },
   ...
)
```

So i can i return the array from the soap and display it!?
I'm sorry for my english, i hope you could help me :)
The best for me will only display the "hostname string" from the array as button is it possible?

Comment: @John: this is Java and on Android Platform

Comment: Yes it's and android platform, could you help me ? Sorry for my english .. do you understand what i try to explain ? thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what your asking, but if you method returns an array of objects you can print that object out like this:

```
 for(int i=0; i < myArray.length; i++){
       Object item = myArray[i];
      // Put into a TextView here if you wish, just printing to console
      System.out.println("Item: "+i +" IP: "+item.ip);
      // or if it is private with a getter
      System.out.println("Item: "+i +" IP: "+item.getIp());

      System.out.println("Hostname: "+item.hostname);

      System.out.println("Hostname: "+item.getHostname());
 }
```

I think that gives you the idea anyway?

Comment: "can't make it working" isn't very precise... what is the error you got?

Answer (score 0):

this blog post might help: http://seesharpgears.blogspot.com/2010/10/web-service-that-returns-array-of.html

see the last method.

edit:

instead of casting to array your `resultRequestSOAP`, you should get the number of properties with `resultRequestSOAP.getPropertyCount()`, and cycle through them to get each object:

`SoapObject pii = (SoapObject)resultRequestSOAP.getProperty(i);`

from these objects you can extract their own properties (vps_id, ip, hostname...) with:

`vps_id = Integer.parseInt(pii.getProperty(0).toString());`

and so on. in the example they're building an array of their Category objects, but of course you can use the data like you want.

Comment: Hi bingstones, i tried to implement this but still not working :( could you help me ?